# Como ler os dados de uma classe

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

Tenho uma api que ao receber os dados preenche uma classe, eu quero fazer um while nesta classe tb_dados_api e tb_carrinho, pegar os dados para gravar no banco, como eu poderia fazer isso? Agradeço

Aqui estou recebendo os dados

```
  [HttpPost]
        [Route("unidade/carrinho/ConsultaUnidadeAtendimento")]
        public HttpResponseMessage ConsultaUnidadeAtendimento(TB_DADOS_API consultaAtendimento)
        {

            try
            {

                string numeroCarrinho =   consultaAtendimento.NumeroCarrinho.ToString();
                string cep = consultaAtendimento.Cep;
                bool retiraLocal = consultaAtendimento.RetiraNoLocal;

                var tTabela = new ConsultaUnidadeEstoque();
                var listar = tTabela.SelecionaUnidadeAtendimento(cep);
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new { dados = listar.ToArray() });
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ex.Message);
            }

        }
```

Eles preenche as classe:

```
public class TB_DADOS_API
    {
        [JsonProperty("numeroCarrinho")]
        public long NumeroCarrinho { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("itens")]
        public List<TB_CARRINHO> Itens { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("cep")]
        public string Cep { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("retiraNoLocal")]
        public bool RetiraNoLocal { get; set; }
    }

    public class TB_CARRINHO
    {
        [JsonProperty("codigo")]
        public string Codigo { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("qtd")]
        public int Qtd { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: ta usando Entity framework ou outro orm ?

Comment: Não estou usando Entity framework, eu tenho a classe preenchida, quero ler os dados e gravar no banco

Comment: pode usar foreach para ter acesso aos objetos e salvar todo em uma tabela coloquei o exemplo ai na resposta

Comment: Agradeço imensamente a ajuda, minha ideia era fazer este foreach dentro do metodo ConsultaUnidadeEstoque e não neste local, porque lá eu tenho uma rotina que vai selecionar onde vai ser gravado os itens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No seu caso pode usar foreach

```
[HttpPost]
        [Route("unidade/carrinho/ConsultaUnidadeAtendimento")]
        public HttpResponseMessage ConsultaUnidadeAtendimento(TB_DADOS_API consultaAtendimento)
        {

            try
            {

                string numeroCarrinho =   consultaAtendimento.NumeroCarrinho.ToString();
                string cep = consultaAtendimento.Cep;
                bool retiraLocal = consultaAtendimento.RetiraNoLocal;
                var tTabela = new ConsultaUnidadeEstoque();
                var listar = tTabela.SelecionaUnidadeAtendimento(cep);

                foreach(var item in consultaAtendimento.itens){
                    //  chamar seu repositorio para gravar item 
                    //item aqui ja é objeto exemplo você ja pode pegar 
                    //item.codigo ou item.qtd
                }

                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new { dados = listar.ToArray() });
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ex.Message);
            }

        }
```

Comment: Eduardo, eu conseguir fazer da forma como queria, eu só precisei enviar :
var listar = tTabela.SelecionaUnidadeAtendimento(consultaAtendimento);

Comment: Mais a sua ideia também deu certo.